# Populate a JComboBox with list of Users from a text file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I have created a JFrame application in Netbeans, which has user creation and user log in for a tutorial application I am making, how would I populate a JComboBox from a text file when a user is created?

I have created the application/user creation, But I am stuck on the JComboBox selection from the file... I have seen multiple things on how to, but nothing is working at this time.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ttMGOOY.jpg]

The application takes a persons:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Desired Username (The thing I want in the JComboBox)

And the log-in is literally just selecting the user from the JComboBox and listing all users created and clicking a button to log-in. The text file is located: F:\ProjectDecember\Users.txt

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Your question is very broad, and as such risks being closed. You mention requirements but have not told us at what specific step you're stuck on. If you haven't started yet, then please close this question, first try to start on your own by breaking down your problem into its constituent steps, and then try to solve each one. If you have started, then please improve your question by isolating the one step you're stuck on, and then by asking your more specific question on this step, complete with code, preferably an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Create a POJO of the data, add the data to a `DefaultComboBoxModel`, apply the model to the `JComboBox`. You will need a custom `ListCellRenderer` which is capable of rendering your POJO. Take a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/).

It shows how you can create a custom renderer for your custom Object that you add to the combo box. It also shows an approach that you can use so you don't break the default functionality of the combo box when you use this custom renderer.

Comment: Thank you, I shall give it a shot :)